# perl + match exactly IP ADDRESS but ignore spaces and TABS

Tags: linux, perl, shell, ksh

the following perl liner code will match exactly the IP address

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$ip=shift(@ARGV);} 
    print if /^\Q$ip\E$/;' "$IP_ADDRESS"  $FILE
```

the problem is that we cant match by the following perl code if space or TAB before or after the $IP_ADDRESS

please advice what need to add to my code in order to ignore spaces and tabs ?

examples from my linux machine

```
$ echo "192.9.200.1" |
    perl -ne 'BEGIN{$ip=shift} 
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/;' "192.9.200.1"
192.9.200.1  ( MATCH )

$ echo " 192.9.200.1" |
    perl -ne'BEGIN{$ip=shift} 
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/;' "192.9.200.1"
NO MATCH

echo "192.9.200.1 " |
    perl -ne'BEGIN{$ip=shift}
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/' "192.9.200.1"
NO MATCH
```

expected results

```
echo "192.9.200.1 "|
    perl -ne'BEGIN{$ip=shift}
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/;' "192.9.200.1"
should MATCH

echo "192.9.200.1"|
    perl -ne'BEGIN{$ip=shift}
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/;' "192.9.200"
should NOT MATCH

echo "192.9.200.1"|
    perl -ne'BEGIN{$ip=shift}
        print if/^\Q$ip\E$/;' "192.9.200."
should NO MATCH
```

Comment: Have you tried `perldoc perlre`?

Comment: `\s*` matches optional white-space, so `/^\s*\Q$ip\E\s*$/`.

Comment: grep "192.9.200.1" file 192.9.200.1 1.1.1.1 perl -ne'BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); } print if /^\s*\Q$ip\E\s*$/; ' "192.9.200.1" file  , no results , the IP in the file but the perl command not print anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
print if /(^|\s)\Q$ip\E(\s|$)/;
```

Comment: maybe now it ignore space but its not match exactly for example : echo " 192.9.200.1" | perl -ne'BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); }     print if /\Q$ip\E/; '  "192.9.200"   , its also print the 192.9.200.1

Comment: see my new expected results section

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead

```
 /\s*\Q$ip\E\s*$/
```

\s* matches 0 or more whitespace chars

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Regexp::Common::net](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon)

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE 'say +($_=~/^$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}$/)?q(MATCH):q(NO MATCH)'
192.9.200.1
MATCH
        192.9.200.1
NO MATCH
    192.999.200.1
NO MATCH
```

This has the additional advantage of detecting invalid patterns for IP addresses.

Comment: i cant use it because I dont have the module ( I cant install new moduls on my linux machine )

Answer (score 0):

You could trim leading and trailing whitespace first:

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $ip = shift @ARGV; }
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    print if /^\Q$ip\E$/; 
' "$IP_ADDRESS"  $FILE
```

Comment: perl -ne ' BEGIN { $ip = shift @ARGV; } s/^\s+|\s+$//g; print if /^\Q$ip\E$/; ' "192.9.200.1" file - not work I have the IP 192.9.200.1 with space in file but still not matched